# making my footer icons not stack on top of each other while reducing the width of my page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using bootstrap 3 to build my webpage and I'm using a footer along the bottom to contain links to various social media pages using small  24x24 icons.  when the page is wide enough they all line up next to each other (floating to the right), however when I condense the page they stack on top of each other, making the footer very tall, how would I go about changing this so that even when they go onto a smaller screen, such as a condensed PC window, a phone, or tablet, they stay next to each other, rather that stacking on top of each other.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    <div class = "navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class = "container">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://www.facebook.com/"><img src=facebook.png></a></li>
                <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://plus.google.com/"><img src=google-plus.png></a></li>
                <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://twitter.com/"><img src=twitter.png></a></li>
                <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://uk.linkedin.com/"><img src=linkedin.png></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the navbar-nav from your unordered list and add display:inline-block to your list-items like this:

HTML:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "container">
        <ul class = "nav navBot navbar-right">
            <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://www.facebook.com/"><img src=facebook.png></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://plus.google.com/"><img src=google-plus.png></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://twitter.com/"><img src=twitter.png></a></li>
            <li><a target = "_blank" href = "https://uk.linkedin.com/"><img src=linkedin.png></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navBot li  {
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/41/